# Scala Set Hashcode

Tags: scala, hashcode

Assume we have three sets of strings in Scala. One has elements A,B,C. Two has elements B,C,D. And Three has elements J,K,I.

My first question is, is there any way that the hashcodes for any two of these sets could be the same? 
My second question is, if I add D to One and A to Two to get new Sets One.n and Two.n, are the hashcodes for One.n and Two.n the same?

Comment: half of your question can be answered by just using the REPL for 3 minutes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Question 1) In general yes, entirely possible. A hashcode is a limited number of bytes long. A Set can be any size. So hashcodes cannot be unique (although usually they are).

Question 2) Why not try it?

```
scala> val One = collection.mutable.Set[String]("A", "B", "C")
One: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(A, B, C)

scala> One.hashCode
res3: Int = 1491157345

scala> val Two = collection.mutable.Set[String]("B", "C", "D")
Two: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] = Set(B, D, C)

scala> Two.hashCode
res4: Int = -967442916

scala> One += "D"
res5: One.type = Set(A, B, D, C)

scala> Two += "A"
res6: Two.type = Set(B, D, A, C)

scala> One.hashCode
res7: Int = -232075924

scala> Two.hashCode
res8: Int = -232075924
```

So, yes they are, as you might expect, since you would expect the `==` method to be true for these two instances.

Comment: Prior to asking the question, I did try it. I should have said, "... One.n and Two.n always the same?" Is it still invariant?

Comment: The rule for `hashCode` is: if your objects `a`, `b` report being equal, i.e., if `a.equals(b)`, then `a.hashCode == b.hashCode` (but not the other way around).

Comment: @user592419 yes it is, but you probably shouldn't rely on it, as hashcodes are implentation details rather than specified public class members. E.g. someone could make a subclass that overrides the hashCode method to return a random number.

Comment: Maybe this is another question altogether then, but I was using hashCode as a caching strategy. That seems to be failing (even though I suspect it shouldnt be) for this small project. Anything you can point me to for a different strategy? I basically need this property of sets in the caching (that it doesnt matter what order something was added. As long as all items in the set are the same, it returns the same value)

Comment: @user592419 Why not just test for equality rather than the hashcodes? Or store your sets in a set of sets, which will automatically mean you only store unique copies.

Comment: The problem with the latter is that the heap space gets crushed. I may have a workaround, will try and let you know. Thanks Luigi.

Comment: Luigi: If someone overrides hashCode to return a random number they're breaking the hashCode/equals contract. @user592419 if you want to use hashing for caching you have to use a cryptographic hash where the chances of collision are much (much) smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Sets which are equal and don't have anything strange inside them (i.e. anything with an unstable hash code, or where the hash code is inconsistent with equals) should have equal hash codes.  If this is not true, and the sets *are the same type of set*, it is a bug and should be reported.  If the sets are different types of sets, it may or may not be a bug to have different hash codes (but in any case it should agree with equals).  I am not aware of any cases where different set implementations are not equal (e.g. even mutable BitSet agrees with immutable Set), however.

So:

1. hashCode is *never* guaranteed to be unique, but it should be well-distributed in that the probability of collisions should be low
2. hashCode of sets should always be consistent with equals (as long as everything you put in the set has hashCode consistent with equals) in that equal sets have equal hash codes.  (The converse is not true because of point (1).)
3. Sets care only about the identity of the contents, not the order of addition to the set (that's the point of having a set instead of, say, a List)

Comment: Point 2 not quite: hashcode will only always agree with equals if equals is true. Equals could be false but hashcodes could be the same.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - That's what I intended to convey.  I'll fix the wording.